# Can I save some C/C++ structure contents to disk when debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have some big and old C++ program and a few classes with their methods in it that I want to debug. The methods take some structures as input and return some structures as output. During debug, I want to save the input and output structures to disk in some simple format like JSON or XML: it can help me, when I will write my wrappings of the old code to reuse it in my program.

In VS debug mode I can easily see the contents of any structure with my eyes, but by default I cannot properly save it to disk.

Is there any way to save a structure to disk in Debug mode of Microsoft Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, there's certainly a way: write your own code to do this. But no, there is no built-in mechanism of any kind, for something like this. But, the wonders of C++ is that you can simply implement this yourself!

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such feature in VS. The only way you can do this is manually create a file and dump your object to it (it's pretty easy to do so by using an [output stream operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/), but if you want a JSON format, you'll need a json library to do this (like [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) for instance)).

You can protect such code by `#ifdef _DEBUG` to be sure it does not impact release builds:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
std::fstream debugFile( "C:/mydebug.txt", std::ios_base::out );
debugFile << object;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to save a structure to disk in Debug mode of
>   Microsoft Visual Studio?

No, there isn't such a way built-in to VS. Fortunately for you though, you don't have to write it all by yourself. See [this open-source project](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) -- just a tiny excerpt from the docs:

```
using nlohmann::json;

namespace ns {
    // a simple struct to model a person
    struct person {
        std::string name;
        std::string address;
        int age;
    };

    void to_json(json& j, const person& p) {
        j = json{{"name", p.name}, {"address", p.address}, {"age", p.age}};
    }

    void from_json(const json& j, person& p) {
        p.name = j.at("name").get<std::string>();
        p.address = j.at("address").get<std::string>();
        p.age = j.at("age").get<int>();
    }
}

// create a person
ns::person p {"Ned Flanders", "744 Evergreen Terrace", 60};

// conversion: person -> json
json j = p;

std::cout << j << std::endl;
// {"address":"744 Evergreen Terrace","age":60,"name":"Ned Flanders"}

// conversion: json -> person
ns::person p2 = j;

// that's it
assert(p == p2);
```

Answer (score 0):

By means of Visual Studio - no. This is not so simple - you need not only to save, but then restore the objects - which is extra effort. One of the ready solutions is [boost](https://www.boost.org/) [Serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/serialization/doc/) library.